# Compile Templates with External Implementation to Static Library

Tags: c++, templates, makefile, static-libraries

I have some classes that I am trying to compile to an external static library. My linked_list.hpp (header for linked_list I'm trying to compile) looks like:

```
#include "list_base.hpp"

template <typename T>

class Linked_list : public List_base <T> {


    public://
        Linked_list();
        ~Linked_list();

    public://accessor functions
        Linked_list<T> * next();//go to the next element in the list
        Node<T> * get_current_node() const;//return the current node
        T get_current() const;//get the current data
        T get(int index) const;//this will get the specified index and will return the data it holds

    public://worker functions
        Linked_list<T> * push(T value);//push a value into the front of the list
        Linked_list<T> * pop_current();//deletes the current_node--resets the current as the next element in the list!
        Linked_list<T> * reset();//this resets the current to the front of the list
        Linked_list<T> * erase(int index);

    private://variables
        Node<T> * current;//store the current node


};

#include "linked_list.cpp"//grab the template implementation file


#endif
```

All of my code headers go in the "header" directory and the implementation goes in the implementation folders I have. These are passed as -I directories.

My make file command for compiling looks like this:

```
static: $(DEPENDENCIES)
    ar rcs liblist_templates.a node.o list_base.o linked_list.o
```

and upon running it gives me this error ...

```
/usr/bin/ranlib: warning for library: liblist_templates.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)
```

I created a master header file that includes the "linked_list.hpp" and a few other pieces of the library but whenever I include it, it still seems to be looking for the cpp files that are included. What am I doing wrong with this? I want to create a portable library that I can drop into existing projects from this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your library only contains template code, it can not be compiled in itself: for example, the compiler does not know which type will be used as `T` in the linked list.

When you compiled `linked_list.cpp`, the compiler only realized basic syntax checks and generated an empty object file. `ranlib` is then complaining since you ask him to create an empty library out of all these empty object files.

The solution is simple: do nothing! Your client code only needs the source files; it doesn't need to be linked against any library. And you'll always need to ship the `.cpp` files, since the compiler can not do anything without them.

Comment: It should also be noted that `linked_list.cpp` would need to be `#include`d into any translation unit using `Linked_list<T>`.

Comment: It looks like `linked_list.cpp` is already `#include`d in `linked_list.hpp`, so that client code only need to include the header file.

Comment: LOL -- yeah, that's true. Missed that.